# wso2apimanager exceeded the allocated quota error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I created an api in wos2apimanager 1.7 and i'm sending 50request/s through jmeter. After few successful requests, following log is shown repeatedly. API tier is set to unlimited.

```
[2017-02-16 09:46:03,364]  INFO - RoleBasedAccessRateController You cannot access this service since you have exceeded the allocated quota.
```

api definition xml is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="admin--TestAPI2"
     context="/test2"
     version="v1"
     version-type="url">
   <resource methods="POST GET" url-mapping="/num" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
            <then>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--TestAPI2_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                     <http uri-template="http://time.jsontest.com/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--TestAPI2_APIsandboxEndpoint_0">
                     <http uri-template="http://time.jsontest.com/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <resource methods="POST GET" url-mapping="/number" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
            <then>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--TestAPI2_APIproductionEndpoint_1">
                     <http uri-template="http://time.jsontest.com/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--TestAPI2_APIsandboxEndpoint_1">
                     <http uri-template="http://time.jsontest.com/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
         <property name="id" value="A"/>
         <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
      </handler>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
         <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
      </handler>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</api>
```

Comment: what is the resource level and application level tier ?

Comment: application tier is unlimited and what did you mean by resource level tier ?

Comment: check what is resource level throttling her https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Managing+Throttling+Tiers#ManagingThrottlingTiers-Differentlevelsofthrottling

Comment: resource level tier is also set to unlimited. If you know, could you please mention the maximum number of request wso2apimanager can handle ?